# Tomcat + CxF ready for Production?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf

Our new project has Apache CXF based Producer SOAP web services.Now we are planning to move the Web Services to production.We are looking for a suitable Open Source container(Web Server or App Server) for deploying CXF Based Java Web Service.First option came to mind was Tomcat 7 .Just needed expert advice on 
1. Whether combination of CXF and Tomcat based WebServices are currently used in production for other projects ?And is this solution scalable & Reliable ?
2. Are there other options to deploy CXF based webServices other than Tomcat in production ?

Thanks!

Comment: I have personally used tomcat & cxf in production in my previous company. it worked well for us and it was reliable. Our customer base was less and we didn't run into scalability issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 . Whether combination of CXF and Tomcat based WebServices are currently used in production for other projects ? And is this solution scalable & Reliable

It shouldn't give you any issue since it is compatible with a wide variety of application server. We are using Tomcat7 and Tomcat6 to deploy our CXF web services and they are in production for quite some time now without any issue.

> 2 . Are there other options to deploy CXF based webServices other than Tomcat in production ?

There are multiple options to deploy cxf based web-services

> From the docs
>
> - Lightweight containers: deploy services in Jetty, Tomcat or Spring-based containers
> - JBI integration: deploy as a service engine in a JBI container such as ServiceMix, OpenESB or Petals
> - Java EE integration: deploy services in Java EE application servers such as Apache Geronimo, JOnAS, Redhat JBoss, OC4J, Oracle WebLogic,
>   and IBM WebSphere
> - Standalone Java client/server